# How to loop values of a variable through a nested while loop calling on a function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, for-loop, while-loop, nested

I have a while loop that calls on a function (def update(i)) and performs the calculation for the required number of times (until the while loop condition is no longer met) in Python3. What I now want to do is put different values of 'i' through the while loop and therefore through the equation 'dv' (shown below). So when the while loop ends I need the whole process to repeat with the next 'i' value. All the i values are in an np.arange array called 'i_es'. I have tried to implement this with the while loop nested inside a for loop as shown below...

```
import numpy as np

def update(i) :     
    dv = (e_l - v_s[-1] + i*r_m)/tau_m 
    v_s.append(v_s[-1] + (dv*dt))      
    return is_spiked() 

def is_spiked() :
    if v_s[-1] > v_th: 
        v_s[-1] = v_r 
        return True
    return False

r_m = 10 
tau_m = 10 
v_th = -40 
e_l = -70 
v_r = -70
v_s = [v_r]

spike_count = 0
t = 0 
t_total = 1000 
dt = 1

i_e_start = 4
i_e_step = 0.1
i_e_final = 5

i_es = np.arange(i_e_start,i_e_final+i_e_step,i_e_step)

for i in i_es :
    while t < t_total :  
        if update(i) : 
            spike_count += 1 
        t += dt 
    print ("Current = ",+ i, " Spike count = ", + spike_count)
```

However, when I run this I get the following output:

```
Current =  4.0  Spike count =  71
Current =  4.1  Spike count =  71
Current =  4.2  Spike count =  71
Current =  4.3  Spike count =  71
Current =  4.4  Spike count =  71
Current =  4.5  Spike count =  71
Current =  4.6  Spike count =  71
Current =  4.7  Spike count =  71
Current =  4.8  Spike count =  71
Current =  4.9  Spike count =  71
Current =  5.0  Spike count =  71
```

I can see that the current ('i') values are increasing as they should each time but the spike count is not changing.. The answer is always from the first value ('i' = 4) run through the loop.

Can anyone help with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You never reset the value of ``t``, so once it reaches ``t_total`` the first time, the ``while`` loop never executes again.

Comment: @jakevdp Thank you!